# Rest POST API With file_get_contents Not Working IN PHP

Tags: php

i am writing new php post api  how to get output.

URL : http://localhost/webservices/test.php

currently i am using postman for development purpose.when i get request as json i am able to handle.

**JSON Example Request :**

```
{"firstName":"Ram","lastName" :"R"}

$request  = file_get_contents('php://input');
$parameters = json_decode($request,true);

$firstName = $parameters['firstName'];
echo $firstName ; // output will be Ram
```

Now My Question is how can i get reponse from Request Like This

```
firstName=Ram&lastName=R
```

Now how can Get First Name ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sorry do you understand my query

Comment: No explain a little bit more.

Comment: my question is when i get request from web api firstName=Ram&lastName=R then how can store firstName and lastName in variable

Comment: `$var = $_REQUEST['firstname']`

Comment: Not working TarangP

Comment: Exploding request on & and then for each item on = to separate keys from values

Comment: thanks for your help guys below answer working for me

Comment: thanks for u r valuable rly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use following Method to get Values from Header.

```
$fname   = $_GET['firstName'];
echo $fname;
```

your Url will be like:

http://localhost/webservices/test.php?firstName=Ram&lastName=R